# ListView with button at the bottom in Activity with fixed header and footer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-activity, android-button

I am developing an Android Application and I have an Activity that looks like [this](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/6118/layoutut.png). I have a header and a footer that have fixed positions, and a ListView with clickable items in the middle. Below the ListView, I have a button.

It is working when I have a few items, but as I add more items, the button begins to disappear, like [this](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/726/errorhf.png).

When I have more items in that list that can be shown in the page, I have a scroll in the list. If I scroll down [like this](http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/9058/scrollm.png) I can see all the items in the list, but the button is hidden.

I have had a lot of problems before trying to add a ListView inside a ScrollView, so I know it doesn't work. As I am new in Android development, perhaps my XML layout files are a bit confusing, but I have a parent LinearLayout with two RelativeLayouts inside, one for the header and one for the middle and footer. The XML is something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/baseTitle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/buttonHelp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/button_help"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical">

        <LinearLayout   
            android:id="@+id/buttonBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#bdbdbd"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <RelativeLayout   
                android:id="@+id/bottomButtomBar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/myGroups"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@string/myGroups"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:background="@layout/button_meus_grupos"/>
                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/createGroups"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="@string/createGroups"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:background="@layout/button_criar_grupos"/>
                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/configurations"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@string/configurations"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:background="@layout/button_configuracoes"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_above="@id/buttonBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <LinearLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/listContent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ffffff" 
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                    >
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/searchBarLayout"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                            android:layout_height="48dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:background="#ffffff"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:clickable="true"
                        >
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/myGroupsLabel"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/myGroups"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:textColor="#bdbdbd"
                                android:textSize="16dp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                            />
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/ic_search" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                        <View android:layout_height="2dip" 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                            android:background="#cccccc"  
                        />        
                        <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
                        />
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/buttonCreateGroup"
                            android:layout_width="200dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                            android:background="@layout/button_confirm"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/createOneGroup"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="22dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        />
                    </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone have any tips on how can I keep the footer fixed, scroll down until the end of the list and then show the button? I want that it looks like the button is the last item at the List.

EDIT: Entire XML posted

Comment: Can you add the button to the footer?

Comment: I believe I could, but then I would have less space for list items and the button would always be visible. I'd rather that the button was shown only when I scrolled down to the bottom.

Comment: I misunderstood. In that case, you need to add the ListView and Button to a Layout which then scrolls both of them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could achieve the exact requirements I explained above was doing the following:

-In the XML file with the layout of the list items, I added a button with `android:visibility="gone"`.

-In my custom ListView adapter, I always add an empty object in the last position. I simply add an object with a flag that shows it is the last in the list.

-In the method `getView()` that I override in the custom Adapter, I check if the object in the current position has the flag indicating that it is the last in the list. If so, I set the button visibility to VISIBLE, otherwise I fill the other components.

If anyone is facing the same problem and needs some sample code from my solution just ask here.

Answer (score 1):

The `ListView` and the `Button` should be in a `RelativeLayout` and in the Button you should set  `android:layout_below="@id/listview"`

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<Button
    android:layout_below="@id/listview"
    android:id="@+id/buttonCreateGroup"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@layout/button_confirm"
    android:text="@string/createOneGroup"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am trying to use this, but still haven't had success. I think it depends on the properties of all the layouts and views I'm using. Any tips on the properties of the relative layout that you suggested or the properties of the list and button? Height, Width, gravity etc

Comment: Can you post your whole XML?

Comment: Copied and pasted your answer and it didn't give me the effect I want. If the list has too many items it scrolls down until the end of the list, and if the list contains only one or two items now the button is not horizontally centered.

Answer (score 1):

Try it in the following manner:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout                               //Header
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true">     
    </RelativeLayout> 

      <ListView 
         android:layout_below="@+id/header" />

    <RelativeLayout                               //Button(footer)
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/listView" >      
    </RelativeLayout>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="baseTitle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonHelp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottomButtomBar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/myGroups"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="myGroups"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/createGroups"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="createGroups"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/configurations"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="configurations"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13dp" >
                </Button>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/buttonBar"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/listContent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/searchBarLayout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/myGroupsLabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:text="myGroups"
                            android:textColor="#bdbdbd"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" >
                        </ImageView>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <ScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/scroll"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="280dip"
                        android:layout_margin="7dip"
                        android:scrollbars="none" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <ListView
                                android:id="@+id/listview"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
                                android:textColor="#000000" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/buttonCreateGroup"
                                android:layout_width="200dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:text="createOneGroup"
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="22dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When I try that I get the following warning in the XML file: "The vertically scrolling ScrollView should not contain another vertically scrolling widget (ListView)" and when I run the application it really doesn't work.